# I wanted to upsert the incremental data from sql db to sql warehouse using Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, cdc, azure-synapse

I wanted to update and insert (upsert) the incremental data from the azure SQL database to Azure data warehouse using azure data factory

:-> The DB is having the multiple tables.

Comment: There are a couple of really good 3rd parties that provide change data capture (CDC) as well as incremental loading capabilities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-partner-data-integration?wt.mc_id=MVP

Answer (score 0):

You to define a watermark in your source database. A watermark is a column that has the last updated time stamp or an incrementing key. The delta loading solution loads the changed data between an old watermark and a new watermark. The workflow for this approach is depicted in the following diagram.

[image]

For step-by-step instructions, see [this](https://sqlofthenorth.blog/2017/10/17/incremental-etl-loading-with-azure-data-factory-v2/) article. On this article adjust the sink to be Azure SQL Data Warehouse and you kind of have all you need on this article.

Another useful example can be found on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal) Microsoft documentation.